# Writing to registry results in "invalid DWORD" error in Regedit

Tags: vb6, registry, regedit

I need to create the following registry key `SchUseStrongCrypto` at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
```

My code is below. It attempts to write this key but results in an

> "invalid DWORD (32-bit) value"

error message shown in REGEDIT:

[image: Error]

```
Option Explicit

   Private Const REG_SZ As Long = 1 
   Private Const REG_DWORD As Long = 4 

   Private Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000 
   Private Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001 
   Private Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
   Private Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003 

   'Return values for all registry functions
   Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS = 0
   Private Const ERROR_NONE = 0

   Private Const KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1 
   Private Const KEY_ALL_ACCESS = &H3F 


'API Calls for writing to Registry

   Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function RegCreateKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegCreateKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, phkResult As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, ByVal samDesired As Long, phkResult As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function RegQueryValueExString Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As Long, lpType As Long, ByVal lpData As String, lpcbData As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function RegQueryValueExLong Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As Long, lpType As Long, lpData As Long, lpcbData As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function RegQueryValueExNULL Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As Long, lpType As Long, ByVal lpData As Long, lpcbData As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function RegEnumKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegEnumKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal dwIndex As Long, ByVal lpName As String, ByVal cbName As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function RegSetValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegSetValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal Reserved As Long, ByVal dwType As Long, lpData As Any, ByVal cbData As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function RegDeleteKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegDeleteKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String) As Long


  Private Sub SaveValue(hKey As Long, strPath As String, strvalue As String, strData As String)

   Dim ret
   RegCreateKey hKey, strPath, ret
   RegSetValueEx ret, strvalue, 0, REG_DWORD, ByVal strData, Len(strData)
   RegCloseKey ret

End Sub

Private Sub QueryValue(sKeyName As String, sValueName As String)

  Dim lRetVal As Long      
  Dim hKey As Long         
  Dim vValue As Variant    
  Dim Data As Long
  Dim retval As Long 
  Dim lType As Long 
  Dim lValue As Long 
  Dim sValue As String

  lRetVal = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sKeyName, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, hKey) 
  retval = RegQueryValueExNULL(hKey, sValueName, 0&, lType, 0&, Data)
  If retval <> ERROR_NONE Then MsgBox "The Regisrt Key is not existing exist"
  If retval = ERROR_NONE Then
  Select Case lType
           ' Determine strings
           Case REG_SZ:
               sValue = String(Data, 0)

               retval = RegQueryValueExString(hKey, sValueName, 0&, lType, sValue, Data)

               If retval = ERROR_NONE Then
                   vValue = Left$(sValue, Data - 1)
               Else
                   vValue = Empty
               End If

           ' Determine DWORDS
           Case REG_DWORD:
               retval = RegQueryValueExLong(hKey, sValueName, 0&, lType, lValue, Data)

               If retval = ERROR_NONE Then vValue = lValue

           Case Else
               'all other data types not supported
               retval = -1
       End Select

  MsgBox "The Regisrt Settings exist"

  RegCloseKey (hKey) 
       End If
       Call SaveValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319", "SchUseStrongCrypto", "1")  'Call SaveValue Sub to save a value in the Registry

End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()

QueryValue "Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319", "SchUseStrongCrypto"

End Sub
```

Comment: Add your code, your clearly writing to the correct place with the wrong value.

Comment: i need to have a value 1. SaveValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319", "SchUseStrongCrypto", "1") Private Sub SaveValue(hKey As Long, strPath As String, strvalue As String, strData As String)
    
   Dim ret

   RegCreateKey hKey, strPath, ret
   RegSetValueEx ret, strvalue, 0, REG_DWORD, ByVal strData, Len(strData)
   RegCloseKey ret
    
End Sub

Comment: @MC19: Please put your code (as text) in the question itself

Comment: done :) could you have a look  please and suggest how can i improvise!